# How to compare counts of record to a value in a different table based on an id?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'd like to compare the counts of records that fit a certain criteria in one table, to a value in a different table to make sure they match up based on an id.  I have 2 tables, SUMMARY and WORKTABLE

```
SUMMARY
-------------
ID  | Total |  
y83 | 1     |
u34 | 2     |
-------------

Worktable
-------------
ID | Action | Code
y83|  S     |  T1
y83|  S     |  T1
y83|  G     |  M1
u34|  G     |  M1
u34|  G     |  M1
u34|  H     |  L1
```

I am interested in the following count matching to the summary total:

```
select ID, count(ID) from WORKTABLE where ACTION = 'G' and CODE = 'M1' group 
by ID;
```

My question is, how can i compare the counts of the query above to the Total field in the summary table?

Answer (score 0):

This should give you what you need.

This takes your query that has the ID and counts your looking for and does a join on the results of that to your Summary table and only returns ones that match.

```
SELECT *
FROM SUMMARY
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ID, count(ID) AS CountTotal
    FROM WORKTABLE 
    WHERE ACTION = 'G' 
    AND CODE = 'M1'
) SUB ON SUMMARY.ID = SUB.ID AND SUMMARY.Total = CountTotal
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like that? Using `inner join` would be useful:

```
select w.ID, count(w.ID) as WCount, count(s.ID) as SCount
from WORKTABLE w
inner join SUMMARY s on s.ID=w.ID
where w.ACTION = 'G' and w.CODE = 'M1'
group by w.ID;
```